# Kill a view/View controller from memory from another View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am fairly new to Obj-C programming, so please bear with me.

I have a Tab Bar. 1 of the tabs has a table view controller that gets it's data from an SQL database into an array.
In another tab it has a button to reset everything (delete all data). The view controller for this tab successfully deletes the SQL database, however the table is still full of data when going back to the table tab.

How can I unload the table view controller from memory when the button is pressed from this other view controller?

If I simulate a memory warning, then the table clears and is rebuilt when going back to the tab. This is what I am trying to do in code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this using NSNotifications.

In the init method of your 1st view controller put this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(tableViewDataUpdated:)
                                                 name:@"DATA_UPDATED"
                                               object:nil];
```

Create a tableViewDataUpdated method that reloads the array containing the data, and then calls reload on the table view.

In the 2nd view controller, when sql data base gets cleared, call

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"DATA_UPDATED" object:nil userInfo:nil];
    [[NSNotificationQueue defaultQueue] enqueueNotification:notification postingStyle:NSPostASAP];
```

Finally in the dealloc method of the 1st view controller include:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. I shall try it shortly.

Comment: I've created an init on 1st controller, however it's never called.
Also I had to remove the 'userInfo' part of calling the Notification as it said it was undeclared (I don't think it's needed anyway).

Comment: I got it working thanks.
I create the Notification in ViewWillDisappear and remove it in ViewWillAppear.
When the reset button is pressed, it calls the Notification that sets the array=nil and reloads table data.

Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked! Sorry about the userInfo, I had taken a piece of code from my own code and missed removing that. Although adding and removing the 1st view controller as an observer in the viewWillAppear/Disappear methods, I think it makes more sense to do it only once in the view life cycle. Did you try overriding - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle? If that doesn't work, I think it would be ok to add it in the viewDidLoad method as well.

Comment: None of my inits are called in the view controllers I have on tabbar tabs. Not sure why.
I don't have a view controller for the actual tabbar as I used storyboard to add it and the segues are automatic.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`reloadData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) on that `UITableView`.

It is cleared during memory warning, cause a view controller recreates its own view every time it receives this warning (in case it is not currently visible).

Comment: Thanks, I can add reloadData to the ViewDidAppear?
But before that will work, I need to also release the NSMutableArray that stores the data for the table that was read from the database.
How can I call array=nil from a different ViewController?

Comment: I did initially write the question of how do I clear the array in another View Controller. But changed it to how do I unload the view, as they achieved the same result.

Comment: You don't need to release the array from a different view controller. One way you could accomplish what you want is in the first view controller, in the viewWillAppear method (not the viewDidAppear) load the array (which will be empty if you've already deleted all the data) and then call reloadData on the table view. The table view should be empty.

Comment: I did think of this, but not too keen on reloading from the SQLdatabase everytime the view appears, as this can happen often (hence using a temp array). This only needs clearing on the very odd occasion the user wants to reset.

Comment: Just reload your table every time your view appears (in viewWillAppear). It is not expensive operation.

Comment: I don't mind reloading from the array, but I don't want to read the database every time.